# part of procedural mesh not visible in ThreeJS

Tags: angular, three.js

I just finished doing some testing with a model that I created for threeJS. I am generating shapes, bundling them into an npm package and exporting to an angular project, however on the left you can see the html version and on the right is the angular version. They have nearly exactly the same code (one exception being a few member variables in my typescript class and a function I turned into a lambda so I could call `this` inside the update loop). Is there any reason these might be interpreted differently? I have checked the actual data of the object and it is exactly the same. [image]

I am using Angular 9.0.3 with threejs version 0.113.2

This is the code used in both versions
https://hatebin.com/felqminvoc

Comment: It's impossible to help you without knowing what's inside `covering.model`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had 2 three.js imported libraries, one in my project and one in my node dependency. There was a mismatch between the npm packages and as such there was a rendering issue. removing one of the packages fixed the issue.